# SharePoint web hooks without Azure?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, webhooks

Is it possible to create SharePoint web hooks **without Azure**?

I have a requirement where I need push notifications from a SharePoint list, I read that SharePoint web hooks can be used to achieve it, but customer doesn't have an Azure account and looking into possibilities where it can be achieved without using Azure.

Comment: I think it is possible.
Please check the link : 1. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/472cc1/get-push-notification-subscription-in-a-sharepoint-site-2013/ 2. http://www.deviantpoint.com/post/2012/07/27/Push-Notifications-with-SharePoint-2013-based-Windows-Phone-apps.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible.  The premise of WebHooks is that SharePoint Online will HTTP POST to a URL you define when the event happens.  The only thing that is important is that the WebHook service you create and register with SharePoint Online has to be accessible to the SharePoint Online service.  Without getting into specialized networking arrangements with Microsoft this means your service has to be publicly addressable.  Azure is used as a common example because it is publicly addressable, it is a Microsoft product and lots of SharePoint Online customers are also Azure customers.  There is however nothing that would stop you from using your own hosting solution.

Here is a presentation on WebHooks: https://docs.com/OfficeDevPnP/1223/pnp-web-cast-sharepoint-webhooks